# why does my code occur segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I tried to solve algorithm that print out the maximum value.

And it printed out segmentation fault.
I looked up for any memory access, but I couldn't find any mistakes..

Please help me why the code occurs segmentation fault..

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

 int M, A;
 int ans=0;
 struct BC{
    int x, y;
    int C;
    int P;
    bool valid;
 }ap[8];

 int path[2][100];
 int dx[5]={0, 0, 1, 0, -1};
 int dy[5]={0, -1, 0, 1, 0};

 struct people{
     int x, y; 
 }human[2];


void init(){
    memset(path, 0, sizeof(path));
    std::cin>>M>>A;
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
            std::cin>>path[j][i];
        }
    }

for(int i=0; i<A; i++){
    std::cin>>ap[i].x>>ap[i].y>>ap[i].C>>ap[i].P;
    ap[i].valid=true;
}
ans=0;
human[0].x=1;
human[0].y=1;
human[1].x=10;
human[1].y=10;
}

bool pos(int h, int idx){
    int dist=abs(human[h].x-ap[idx].x)+abs(human[h].y-ap[idx].y);
    if(dist<=ap[idx].C) return true;
    return false;
}

int ret=0;
void dfs(int user, int d){
    if(user==2){
        if(ret<d) ret=d;
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<A; i++){
        if(ap[i].valid && pos(user, i)){
            ap[i].valid=false;
            dfs(user+1, d+ap[i].P);
            ap[i].valid=true;
        }
    }
    dfs(user+1, d);
}

void solve(){
    ret=0;
    dfs(0,0);
    ans+=ret;
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            human[j].x+=dx[path[j][i]];
            human[j].y+=dy[path[j][i]];
        }
        ret=0;
        dfs(0,0);
        ans+=ret;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    int TC;
    for(int i=0; i<TC; i++){
        init();
        solve();

        std::cout<<"#"<<i+1<<" "<<ans<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample input is like this:

1

20 3

2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3

4 4 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 1 1 4 1 4 3 3 3 3 3 3

4 4 1 100

7 10 3 40

6 3 2 70

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Name your variables better. This reeks of one of those code challenge sites. I generally am not a fan since the sample output is usually overly simple and they don't provide the input set that caused a failure so you can replicate and debug properly. And the code formatting is off, making it a lot more annoying to try and read.

Comment: Your program invokes *undefined behavior*. Ex: `for (int i = 0; i<TC; i++) {` - ask yourself what the value of `TC` is when you hit that for-loop. If your answer is, "I have no idea", you're in good company, because neither does your program. It's never set to a determinate value. Turn on your compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! It had a problem at TC.....